# I can't combine 2 of one way linked list

Tags: c

I working for combine 2 of one way linked list.

That's my node.

```
  struct node
{
    int x;
    node *next;
};
```

That's the combiner.

```
void combine(struct node *go1,struct node *go2)
{
    while(go1!=NULL) go1=go1->next;
    while(go2!=NULL)
    {
        go1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        go1->x=go2->x;
        go1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        go1=go1->next;
        go2=go2->next;
    }
}
```

And this is the main function.

```
main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head -> x = 5;
    head -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head -> next -> x = 10;
    head -> next -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head -> next -> next -> x = 23;
    head -> next -> next -> next = NULL;

    struct node *head2;
    head2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head2 -> x = 5;
    head2 -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head2 -> next -> x = 13;
    head2 -> next -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head2 -> next -> next -> x = 31;
    head2 -> next -> next -> next = NULL;
    print(head);

    combine(head,head2);
    print(head);

            execute(head);

}
```

print function is custom printing list function. Simple made by me, and execute is free()'s the list. Printing the head, printing just 5,10,23 and again 5,10,23. Not including head2's x values. I want append head2's x's tp head1.

Comment: `while(go1!=NULL)` --> `while(go1->next != NULL)`... `go1->next =malloc(sizeof(node));` ... at last element  `go1->next = NULL;`

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/PJwKDG)

Comment: Also You are using C++ compiler as C compiler.

Comment: edited as yours, and worked. But how, i don't understand and why go1->next ?

Comment: After the pointer becomes NULL, you can not link the node.

Comment: You don't need to allocate any memory to combine the lists; simply make the `next` pointer of the last member of the first list point to the first member of the second list: `assert(go1 != NULL); while (go1->next != NULL) go1 = go1->next; go1->next = go2;`.  Unless you want to preserve the second list as an independent list, of course, in which case you need to append new members to the first list using your standard node creation and add element to list functions.

Answer (score 1):

After this loop

```
while(go1!=NULL) go1=go1->next;
```

the pointer `go1` is equal to `NULL` and the data member `next` of the previous node also equal to `NULL`. If you'll change the pointer `go1`  the data member `next` of the previous node won't be changed because they are different objects occupied different memory extents.

Moreover in general the first list can be empty so initially the parameter `go1` can be equal to NULL and changing this parameter will not change the original list because the function deals with a copy of the value of the original list.

Also the second memory allocation

```
    go1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    go1->x=go2->x;
    go1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

does not make sense. It overwrites the previous value of `go1`. As result there is a memory leak.

The function can be written the following way

```
void combine( struct node **go1, struct node **go2 )
{
    while ( *go1 != NULL ) go1 = &( *go1 )->next;

    for ( ; *go2 != NULL; go1 = &( *go1 )->next, go2 = &( *go2 )->next )
    {
        *go1 = ( node* )malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        ( *go1 )->x = ( *go2 )->x;
        ( *go1 )->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
combine( &head, &head2);
```

Of course there is no need to declare the second parameter as having type `struct node **`. It is enough to declare it like `struct node *`. However in this case the parameters will have different types that can confuse users of the function.